# How to add remember me feature to api login

Tags: javascript, react-native, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm using keycloak on react-native. And process login session with api calls. I want to add remember me feature to my app but i don't know any proper way to do that. Storing user's login information on cache is sounds like insecure. Can i grant access to user with access token or something like that? Thank you for reading. Have a nice day.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think i'm solved the problem. I added[react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) to project. Storing username and password on a encrypted storage. This package also asks for fingerprint before decrypt these informations.